# Protocol in latex longer then one page?

Tags: tabularx, ltxtable

I used the proposed solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408900/how-can-make-a-protocol-in-latex/477003#477003) to make a protocol in latex. 
This works for me but I noticed two things which are not so nice:

- The protocol starts on a new page item.
- If the protocol is longer than a page there is no transition to a new page.

Any suggestions how to force the protocol to start just after my regular text in the middle of the page and then if it cannot fit on that page to proceed on a new page?

Can you provide some minimal working example?

Comment: The answer you linked to uses `tabularx` that can not be broken over pages. To use a table that allows pagebreaks, use `longtable`.

Comment: Will there be a pagebreak within a list?